# Slow reading of millions of files in Fuseblk partitions shared over NFS

Tags: nfs, ntfs, fuse, ntfs-3g

I have two Linux systems: NFSServer1 (RHEL) and NFSClient1 (Ubuntu).

On NFSServer1, `ntfs-3g` driver and `ldmtool` is installed. The `NTFS` device partitions are mounted by executing the command:
`mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro,noatime $devPath $mountPath`

Note: The two partitions `/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1` and `/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2` are Windows Dynamic disk partitions derived using [ldmtool](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/libldm/ldmtool.1.en)

```
[root@ROADQAScaleNFS2 ~]# df -Th
Filesystem                                Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc4                                 fuseblk   127G   11G  117G   9% /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc4
/dev/sdc2                                 fuseblk   450M   13M  438M   3% /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc2
/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1 fuseblk    10G  5.8G  4.3G  58% /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1
/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2 fuseblk    10G  6.0G  4.1G  60% /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2
```

```
[root@ROADQAScaleNFS2 ~]# mount
/dev/sdc4 on /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc4 type fuseblk (ro,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdc2 on /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc2 type fuseblk (ro,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1 on /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1 type fuseblk (ro,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2 on /monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2 type fuseblk (ro,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

**Totally all these partitions have about 10 million files.**

These mounted partitions are accessed from NFSClient1 as NFS shares:

```
[root@NFSClient ~]# mount
10.4.0.5:/monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc4 on /monitor1/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc4 type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.148.66.49,local_lock=none,addr=10.4.0.5)
10.4.0.5:/monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc2 on /monitor1/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/sdc2 type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.148.66.49,local_lock=none,addr=10.4.0.5)
10.4.0.5:/monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1 on /monitor1/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume1 type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.148.66.49,local_lock=none,addr=10.4.0.5)
10.4.0.5:/monitor/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2 on /monitor1/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2 type nfs4 (ro,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.148.66.49,local_lock=none,addr=10.4.0.5)
```

The number of NFS daemon threads on NFS server is set to 64.

Next, on the NFS client, when we issue a stat a `fuseblk` partition using a `find` command:

`find -H /monitor1/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2 -printf '%p|' | xargs -d '|' stat --printf="%F, %i:\t%n\t%.19x\t%.19y\t%.19z\t%.19w\t%s\t%u\t%g\n" \ |$SED -e "s|/monitor1/6f5bd42-e548-4e60-8c5d-4c52360b8dc4/mapper/ldm_vol_VishalWDD-Dg0_Volume2/||g" -e "s|directory,|d/d|g" -e "s|symbolic link,|l/l|g" -e "s|regular file,|r/r|g" -e "s|socket,|h/h|g" \ -e "s|regular empty file,|r/r|g" -e "s|fifo,|p/p|g"`

Its execution is extremely slow. It takes a break of 5-6 minutes and then resumes for a few seconds. The same is true for all other mount points. The execution does not finish even after 12 hours.

**This sluggish behavior is not observed for `ext4` and `xfs` devices types.**

As a test, I tried executing the same find command on the NFSServer1, it was quite fast. The whole execution finished in ~40 minutes. I don't have access to the NFS server though. I have asked the NFS server team to try different mount options as mentioned in the [ntfs-3g man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g), but it didn't help.

If there is any way I could improve the read performance of `fuseblk` partitions over NFS, I would grateful to you guys.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FUSE is a filesystem in userland – due to context switching overhead, it's not ever going to be as fast as an in-kernel file system, and my guess is this hurts even more when you have to do very file-system intense things like a `find` on it.

So.

- Either use the NTFS3 in-kernel driver (as available in Linux 5.15 and on, if I remember correctly), or
- move all the data to a different file system *once* (and synchronize it to NTFS if you ever need that again), or
- run a paravirtualized Windows Server VM to serve that file system via NFS

I'd personally strongly tend towards the second option. What sense does it make to permanently access something from a definitely-not-made-for-that file system? We're talking about not even 40GB of actual data – that's really nothing.

I mean, you have an *NFS Team*. There's people employed to make your data accessible via NFS. Why they even support directly exporting NTFS is a bit beyond me.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 can't be done. Could you please guide on how to install NTFS3 in-kernel driver on RHEL?

Comment: @Amit this is honestly nonsense. If you're allowed to install kernel drivers, you're also allowed to occupy 40 GB of storage on a different file system and only sync back to NTFS if you need it. I'm not going to advise something so illogical. Get rid of your NTFS storage.

Comment: @Amit you lose the certification advantages of RHEL if you try to insert third-party modules (not even sure that exists for NTFS3 for RHEL kernels!), and if you wanted to upgrade your kernel, you'd also lose the kernel binary compatibility of RHEL. Modifying your kernel/loading backported modules: This is really no solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. Could you briefly share the steps/commands to be executed for option 2?

Comment: literally just copying files off the NTFS volumes/partitions. Like. With `cp`. Or with `rsync`, if you want to synchronize.

Comment: Not only are you using NTFS you have LDM which is a Windows proprietary logical volume. Some old info. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv You really want to use Linux tools for Linux and only use Windows tools for Windows.